# How do I update the column in postgresql python?

Tags: python, database, postgresql

I am trying to add a new column in existing table and want to populate that column in database, there is a predictions column which is dataframe it is giving me error what I am doing wrong,

**Code:**

```
conn = create_connection()
cur = conn.cursor()

query = "ALTER TABLE STOCK_MARKET_FORECASTING ADD COLUMN predictions float"
cur.execute(query)

# Inserting predictions in database
def inserting_records(df):
    for i in range(0 ,len(df)):
        values = (df['Predicted_values_Hourly_Interval'][i])
        cur.execute("UPDATE STOCK_MARKET_FORECASTING SET (predictions) VALUES (%s)", values)
    conn.commit()
    print("Records created successfully")
inserting_records(predictions)
```

Comment: Please read the manual for the [UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) for the correct syntax. Where in the manual did you find the syntax you are using?

Comment: I have seen it, can you please post the correct code ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You're passing in a single value – `cur.execute` requires a tuple of values.
2. You're probably looking for `INSERT`, not `UPDATE`. `UPDATE` updates existing rows.

```
def inserting_records(df):
    series = df['Predicted_values_Hourly_Interval']
    for val in series:
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO STOCK_MARKET_FORECASTING (predictions) VALUES (%s)", (val, ))
    conn.commit()
```

might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Error is occuring : NotNullViolation: null value in column "date" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, null, null, null, null, 1.1439418).

Comment: Well, you'll need to figure out the values for the rest of the columns for your table.

Comment: I have 5 columns in which each column has 30 values already, I m trying to make a new column in database and want to insert this 30 values of prediction dataframe to new column respectively

Comment: I have already values in my database , i don't know why it is giving me null value error

Comment: If you're `INSERT`ing new rows, you'll need to insert all the non-null columns, of course. If you were to use `UPDATE`, you would need a `WHERE` clause too, or you'd update all rows in the table with a single value. Your original code has no indication as to what you'd use for `WHERE`.

Comment: Can you please edit your code that How can i create a new column in existing table and populate the predictions with that existed columns

Comment: I can't do that, because I don't know how your `df`'s rows would match to the database rows.